# Narrowing down current apache redirect statement that is too broad

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I currently have these two redirect statements -

```
RedirectMatch permanent "/(.*)\.html$" "https://www.example.com/archive/blog/$1"
RedirectMatch permanent "/(.*)" "https://www.example.com/archive/blog"

RedirectMatch permanent "/(.*)\.html$" "https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog/$1"
RedirectMatch permanent "/(.*)" "https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog"
```

What I want to have happen, is when someone is on the spanish page, they will be redirected to the spanish www.example.com page.  This is want corresponds to the second set to rules here.

What is happening now is that both the spanish and the english URL's are matching on the  first redirect rule since they both have .html endings, so it will always redirect to the first rule only.

How can I set up these two redirect statements so that the difference in the URL is picked up?

As an example - With these rules, going to - `http://www.oldsite.com/2016/11/article.html` will redirect me to the first rule, which is correct.

If I make it the URL - `http://www.oldsite-es.com/2016/11/article.html` it redirects me to the first rule as well, which is incorrect since it is an es (spanish) page.

EDIT -

This is one new redirect statement I have tried that isnt quite working -

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = '^oldsite-es\.com$'">
   RedirectMatch permanent "/(.*)\.html$" "https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog/$1"
   RedirectMatch permanent "/(.*)" "https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog"
</If>
```

How can I modify the redirect rules to work with both of these URL hosts?

Comment: this something that you are trying to redirect from an old URL to new one?

Comment: Yeah, www.oldsite.com/...../olddocument.html to www.example.com/..../newdocument.html, and www.oldsite-es.com/.../olddocument.html to www.example-es.com/.../newdocument.html.  Basically the current statements are too greedy, and dont distuinguish between the two different hsot URL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your comments you need to use mod_rewrite instead of Mod_alias so you can match based on the hostname and get creative with the matching to have one rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldsite(-es)?\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example%1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is the `{REQUEST_URI}` section what would allow it to match what was after the trailing URL / to the new site?  EX - oldsite.com/somestuff/document to the new URL as www.example.com/somestuff/document?